# Закрытие консольного приложения по требуемой кнопке

Tags: windows, c++, консоль

Как в С++ сделать консольное приложение, чтобы оно не закрывалось простым нажатием на кнопку (x) или ESC. А закрывалась, например, когда нажимаешь на клавиатуре кнопку (s).
Использую Code::Blocs.

Comment: Что за программу пишете?

Comment: Надо, чтобы на экране висели слова, и никто кроме меня, не мог их закрыть.

Comment: Как создать приложение без окна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказали лучше сделай в Win32 application, Консоли не будет, и следовотельно Х тоже, но его можно закрыть из диспетчера задач в процессах, но и для этого есть обход, почитах книгу, самоучить С++ "глазами хакера", там все детально описоно...

Comment: "Программирование на С++ глазами хакера", автор Михаил Фленов? Да, именно там и описана работа с системой, в т.ч. советы, которые могут помочь в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Надо создать приложение без окна. Пусть просто делает что-то в бэкграунде.

А если надо обязательно с консолью, то нафига блокировать кнопку [x] ?

Comment: Ну так как создать приложение без окна? И чтоб ESC тож не работала !

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать установить клавиатурный хук WH_KEYBOARD_LL и в нем отслеживать нажатия клавиш и одновременно поставить обработчик на закрытие консоли SetConsoleCtrlHandler.

Comment: мне интерестно как создать приложение без окна ? можете сразу пример написать ?

Answer (score 0):

Вам интересно, чтоб именно без окна, или консоль? Если первое, то просто создайте приложение Win32, и измените в функции `BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)` функцию `ShowWindow` так: `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);`, тогда у Вас окно будет скрыто. А обработчик нажатия клавиши можете вставить в функции main, в главном цикле обработки сообщений, он генерируется Мастером.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windef.h>
int main(){
char title[512];
memset(title,0,512)
GetConsoleTitleA(title,511);//получаем заголовок окна.
HWND    hWnd=FindWindowA(NULL,title); // получаем Handle окна.
HMENU hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, false);//получаем Handle системного меню.
if (hMenu!=NULL){
       EnableMenuItem(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED);//делает крестик серым(не актвным).
       DeleteMenu(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);//удаляет "Закрыть." из контексного меню окна.
        }
//А для закрытия окна кнопку 's', тебе пидется создать простой обработчик клавишь:
while(true){
Sleep(100); //что бы не повесить комп.
/*
твой код. 
*/
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_S)){/* функция завершения для твоего кода*/ return 0;}// VK_S или (0x53) 
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)){continue;}//VK_ESCAPE или (0x1B), перехватываем нажетие "ESCAPE"
}
 return 0; 
}
////   Win XP, VS2008, это чистый WinAPI, попробуй может и заработает на Code::Blocs
```